# if statement in fish_prompt

Tags: shell, prompt, fish

I'm trying to customize my fish prompt but i can't seem to put an if statement in it.
What I want : `user@host ~/.config [127]>`
What i tried :

```
function fish_prompt 
    echo -n $USER
    echo -n "@"
    echo -n $hostname
    echo -n " "
    echo -n (prompt_pwd)
    echo -n (__fish_git_prompt)
    if [ $status -ne 0 ] 
        echo -n " [$status] "
    end 
    echo -n "> "
end
```

I want the $status to show only when there is an error.
So far, everything works except the `if` statement. (i tried the same `if` directly in the console and it worked, the problem occurs only in the fish_prompt) .
Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`echo` also returns a status, so $status is updated.

So if you are interested in the commandline's $status, you need to save that before doing anything else.

Do this:

```
function fish_prompt
    # $status here is what the commandline returned,
    # save it so we can use it later
    set -l laststatus $status
    echo -n $USER
    echo -n "@"
    echo -n $hostname
    echo -n " "
    echo -n (prompt_pwd)
    echo -n (__fish_git_prompt)
    if [ $laststatus -ne 0 ] 
        echo -n " [$laststatus] "
    end 
    echo -n "> "
end
```

This is also what fish's sample prompts do